# when there are 2 array results in sql and each result containing 5 answers..then how to compare the 2 arrays element by element.?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

here "user" is a table name and a_i are the answers to the 5 questions answered in the quiz...
now if i want to compare these two results like comparing the ans1  of the user 1 and user 2 what is the code i need to write...
basically what i am thinking of is i will store all the coorrect answers in the users table under the user_id=1 and when other users play the quiz i will
manage to store the results in the same table.. while evaluating i will compare the every user with user_id=1.... so now how to compare....

$sql="select a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5  from
                   users
           where user_id=1";
$result1=mysql_query($sql);

$sql="select a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5  from
                   users
           where user_id=2";
$result2=mysql_query($sql);

Answer (score 1):

Do a self join on the user table and use aliases like so

```
    FROM USER answer, USER contestant
   WHERE answer.id = 1
     and contestant.id = 2
```

Then use the [If function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) in your select clause to output correctness such as

```
SELECT IF(answer.a_1 = contestant.a_1, 'Yes', 'No') as A_1_Successful
```

This should allow you to reduce your sql calls.

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there.  You can now do this:

```
compare($result1[a_1], $result2[a_1]);
```

The `compare` function can be done any way you need.